# Waitress on Heroku giving error

Tags: django, heroku, procfile, waitress

I am trying to switch from Gunicorn to Waitress on Heroku. In the logs, I keep getting an error from Waitress:

```
Error: Bad module 'cardisle'
```

In my procfile, I have:

```
web: waitress-serve --port=$PORT cardisle.wsgi:application
```

If I remove the `.wsgi` extension, I get a different error:

```
Error: Bad object name 'application'
```

I have tried changint the object name to `wsgifunc` as well since it's in the Waitress doc, but no luck.

Any help would be appreciated. I have a wsgi.py file with the following:

```
import os
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "cardisle.settings")
import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here's an awful fact about waitress: it is hiding info from you.

If you look at the [source](https://github.com/Pylons/waitress/blob/master/waitress/runner.py#L204-L206), "Bad Module" is code for "There was a failure importing your application from the wsgi module."

**To see the error,** try:

1. logging into a dyno with `heroku run bash`
2. navigating to the directory with wsgi.py in it (with `cd`)
3. opening a shell with `python`
4. running `import wsgi`

When I hit this error and did this, I got:

```
~/proj/proj $ python

Python 2.7.9 (default, Dec 11 2014, 17:18:51) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import wsgi

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "wsgi.py", line 36, in <module>
    application = get_wsgi_application()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 14, in get_wsgi_application
    django.setup()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 85, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 86, in create
    module = import_module(entry)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)

ImportError: No module named debug_toolbar
```

Which is a much more helpful error.  In my case, I had set DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE to 'local' in production, (which did not have the appropriate requirements,) and so the import failed.

The exact nature of your problem will vary, but I'll mention a case that frustrated me when I started out:

If you are running `web: waitress-serve --port=$PORT cardisle.wsgi:application`, you may need to change your PYTHONPATH environment variable so that PYTHONPATH+cardisle.wsgi is a fully-formed extant path on the machine in question.

I'll open a PR for waitress this evening that tries to bubble up the import error.  Best of luck otherwise!

Comment: I made a pull request to waitress to add exception information to the error output, and the maintainer likes it.  We did it everyone!

Answer (score 0):

The wsgi.py file should be in the cardisle directory.  Waitress is trying to import cardisle.wsgi.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the answer. If your project is laid out like this (as they are by default):

```
cardisle/
  cardisle/
    wsgi.py
  app1/
  app2/
  app3/
```

Try this Procfile instead:

```
web: waitress-serve --port=$PORT cardisle.cardisle.wsgi:application
```

I thought of this because Dave Hall's sample project has a different layout:

```
projectname/
  wsgi.py
  apps/
    app1/
    app2/
    app3/
```

Which has the `wsgi.py` file at a higher level. You probably followed his tutorial, but as far as I can tell the default Django layout doesn't quite work like that.

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying your WSGI file like this(For Django 1.7):

```
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

I had the same error because before, my Procfile was configured as explained on the Heroku guide:

```
 from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
 from dj_static import Cling

 application = Cling(get_wsgi_application())
```

And this was causing an issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

```
cardisle:wsgi.application
```

Not `carlisle"."wsgi":"application`